# Hourly Updates in Excel (active Timers)

Tags: vba, excel, updates

I'm a noob that is trying to make a good impression as I start my recent job. I am not very good at Excel, but I am trying to learn! This website has been a great resource, but I have a question.

We have a program that is like an active clock that ticks along and counts faults, rejections, product coming from an assembly line.

I would like to be able to create a graph that by the hour tells us the amounts for each so we can look at trends and set goals and stuff. My first thought was to find a macro that can take screen shots every hour, but I figure that would require manual entry for 24 times a day.

Has anyone have a better idea or know a macro I could use?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you able to pull data into excel? Once you get raw data into excel pivot tables can help this process.

Comment: I tried to find it. There is other raw data tables attached to the main hub with a crazy amount of data, which I was hoping to avoid. Maybe this is a bit over my head. I was hoping to just find something to record the data by the hour on the side. I'm sure it's in the "complicated" data but I'll have to dig it out.

Comment: Perhaps an SQL query from excel to the data tables? Then you can select the fields you want instead of having to filter through a lot of data. Even if that doesn't work and you have a lot of information in Excel, it'd just mean some extra scrolling when setting up a pivot table and a somewhat bloated spreadsheet. Not the end of the world.